# Closing sub-processes spawned by CreateProcess

Tags: windows, winapi, process, subprocess, createprocess

I'm working with *CreateProcess* to run a process/application of mine.
The purpose is to run it, do something, wait for some indication, and close it (Using *TerminateProcess*).

What I noticed is that this application/process creates sub-processes.
Additionally, when terminating the created process, the sub-processes **do not** terminate, and still remain for a period of time.

I wanted to ask if there's an option to somehow kill all the sub-processes with the main process.
It causes issues, since when I do *CreateProcess* again, there are leftovers from previous processes, and I think they're causing some issues.

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Windows [Job Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Jobs are like process groups; the operating system will take care of terminating all processes in the job once the job leader (your initial process) is terminated. This even works if the proess leader crashes.

Comment: I've read about this in several posts, the problem is that I don't have access to these processes, nor I can inject code to them. Therefore, I can't really add the created sub-processes to the Job object, and close it as a whole :(

Comment: @fashasha: The MSDN page I linked explains: `After a process is associated with a job, by default any child processes it creates using CreateProcess are also associated with the job. [..] This default behavior can be changed by setting the extended limit JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK or JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_SILENT_BREAKAWAY_OK for the job.`. This means that unless you as the job creator explicitely allow it, child processes will automatically become part of the job.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a process using *CreateProcess* you'll get a **LPPROCESS_INFORMATION**-pointer.
It contains the process handle. You'll need to close the processes manually, as there is no such thing as a process hierarchy as in Linux/Unix.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for CreateProcess and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the **PROCESS_INFORMATION**-structure.

Comment: `PROCESS_INFORMATION` does not tell you about the sub-processes. You would have to enumerate running processes looking for ones that have the `PROCESS_INFORMATION.dwProcessID` as their owner PID, possibly even recursively so you can handle multiple layers of sub-processes.

Comment: Remy, how can I run through all the processes and look for the ones that match? Also, do you believe it's a **time consuming operation**? If so, I'll have to skip it. For now, I know the names of the processes (They're not likely to change) and use `taskill` to force them to die. This is a very crude solution, but it works for now. I'd like to have some less hacky...

Comment: @RemyLebeau Windows does not have anything like a process-tree (unline Unix-like OS's), in that case you cannot clearly determine which process spawned which processes.

Comment: @bash.d: That's plain wrong, you can easily build a process tree in Windows since you can get the parent process ID for any given process ID from a snapshot created with [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Possibly you can create your own process tree, but Windows itself does not contain a process tree!

Comment: @bash.d: if Windows did not have any concept of parent/child processes, then `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` would not be able to provide that information, but it actually does. The [`PROCESSENTRY32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839.aspx) struct has a `th32ParentProcessID` field that is documented as "The identifier of the process that created this process (its parent process)". And tools like SysInternals Process Explorer do display a process tree.  So Windows obviously does have a concept of parent/child processes. It just doesn't expose that in most APIs.